# Удаление одинаковых элементов в отсортированном листе (списке)

Tags: python, алгоритм, list

Например, у меня есть лист `x = [a, a, a, f, h, k, k]`. Мне надо сделать, что бы в этом листе было только одно `a` и одно `k`, т.е. удалить лишние похожие элементы, остальные не трогать. Похожие элементы всегда рядом, т.к. лист просортирован. Как реализовать удаление этих лишних элементов?

Comment: связанный вопрос: [In Python, what is the fastest algorithm for removing duplicates from a list so that all elements are unique *while preserving order*?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/89178/4279)

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89178/in-python-what-is-the-fastest-algorithm-for-removing-duplicates-from-a-list-so

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Можно использовать модуль itertools:

```
from itertools import groupby

x = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'f', 'h', 'k', 'k']

new_x = [el for el, _ in groupby(x)]

print(new_x)    # ['a', 'f', 'h', 'k']
```

Способ лучше варианта с set тем, что itertools.groupby сохраняет тот порядок, в котором элементы шли в изначальной последовательности. В то время, как set не гарантирует сохранения порядка.

Comment: Оптимальный вариант

Comment: только я ю делал это через itertools.Counter

Comment: способ сработает только для предварительного отсортированного списка

Comment: @vadimvaduxa В вопросе указано, что список отсортирован

Comment: даже рецепт есть готовый: [`unique_justseen()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes): `map(itemgetter(0), groupby('aaafhkk'))` см. [`more_itertools` пакет](http://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.unique_everseen)

Answer (score 16):

Проще всего так:

```
>>> l = [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 5]
>>> print list(set(l))
[1, 2, 3, 5]
>>>
```

Отсортирован ли изначальный список, значения не имеет.
Однако, способ не универсален, например:

```
>>> l = [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, [4, 5, 6]]
>>> print list(set(l))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Универсальный способ:

```
def f(l):
    n = []
    for i in l:
        if i not in n:
            n.append(i)
    return n


print f([1, 1, 2, 3, 3, [4, 5, 6]]) # [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6]]
print f([[1, 2], [1, 2], 3, 4, 4, 'oops', 'oops']) # [[1, 2], 3, 4, 'oops']
```

---

Если (как в условии) входящий список так или иначе отсортирован, в последнем алгоритме (функция f) вместо

```
if i not in n:
   n.append(i)
```

можно написать

```
if not n or i != n[-1]:
   n.append(i)
```

что существенно улучшит эффективность.

Comment: способ совсем не универсален, тк работает только для вложенности первого порядка

Comment: @vadimvaduxa ??? `print f([[1, [2]], [1, [2]], 3, 4, 4, 'oops', 'oops']) --> [[1, [2]], 3, 4, 'oops']`

Comment: `set(L)` не гарантирует сохранения порядка, если хочется его сохранить, то [можно `OrderedDict.fromkeys(L)` использовать](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7961425/4279). Функция `f()` квадратична (`O(n**2)`), можно `groupby(sorted(L))`  использовать (`O(n log n)`), если элементы нехэшируемые. Иллюстрация: если `n` миллион, то квадратичный алгоритм требует порядка `1000_000_000_000` операций, а `O(n log n)` только порядка `10_000_000` (если ввод задачи не ограничен условиями, то полезно следить за трудоёмкостью алгоритма (по порядку величины)).

Answer (score 3):

```
import itertools
x = 2, 2, 4, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 5, 4, 2, 1
print('data1:', x)


# простой спрособ - set, но теряется сортировка исходного списка
r = set(x)
print('set:', r)


# способ groupby подходит не совсем, тк уникальны только элементы идущие подряд
r = [a[0] for a in itertools.groupby(x)]
print('неверно groupby no sort:', r)

r = set(a[0] for a in itertools.groupby(x))
print('верно groupby no sort:', r)

# если список сначала отсортировать
r = [a[0] for a in itertools.groupby(sorted(x))]
print('groupby sort:', r)


# способ при котором не теряется сортировка исходного списка
def unique(obj: iter):
    args = []
    for a in obj:
        if a not in args:
            args.append(a)
            yield a

r = unique(x)
print('original sort unique:', *r)


# если список вложенный и заранее неизвесна степень вложенности
x = 2, (2, 4), [3], [3, [1, [1, 2, ([5],)], [4]], 2, 1]
print('\ndata2:', x)

def unpack(obj: iter):
    for o in obj:
        if isinstance(o, (list, tuple)):
            yield from unpack(o)
        else: yield o

r = unique(unpack(x))
print('unpack', *r)
```

out:

```
data1: (2, 2, 4, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 5, 4, 2, 1)
set: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
неверно groupby no sort: [2, 4, 3, 1, 2, 5, 4, 2, 1]
верно groupby no sort: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
groupby sort: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
original sort unique: 2 4 3 1 5

data2: (2, (2, 4), [3], [3, [1, [1, 2, ([5],)], [4]], 2, 1])
unpack 2 4 3 1 5
```

Answer (score 3):

Если использовать множество для получения списка уникальных элементов, то для получения списка с сохранением порядка следования элементов, можно использовать сортировку по индексу изначального списка. К примеру так:

```
x = [a, a, a, f, h, k, k]
y = sorted(set(x), key=lambda d: x.index(d))
print(y)  # [a, f, h, k]
```

Answer (score 2):

Задача с такими простыми и понятными начальными данными решается просто, без каких либо хешей, множеств и прочего, с минимальной трудоемкостью.
Учитываем что массив отсортирован, но из этого знания используем только то, что одинаковые элементы идут подряд.

```
x = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'f', 'h', 'k', 'k', 1]

r = [x[0]]
i = 1
j = 0
while i < len(x):
    if r[j] != x[i]:
        r.append(x[i])
        j += 1
    i += 1

print r
```

Answer (score 0):

```
de = ['a','a','a','f','h','k','k']

for i in de:
    while de.count(i) > 1:
        de.remove(i)
```

Comment: Вам приз за самое неффективное решение - порядка O^2 ))  Не делайте вообще так - удалять элементы из списка по которому итерируетесь может когда-нибудь привести к проблемам

Comment: @CrazyElf .Мы с вами прекрасно знаем что эти проблемы возникнут только в случае наличия обращения к индексу элемента в списке в рамках цикла. Не стоит так предвзято относиться к простому и понятному решению проблемы в рамках ДАННОЙ задачи и искать сложности там, где их на самом деле нет. За что Вы получаете приз, я думаю Вы уже догадались.

Answer (score -1):

Зачем такие сложности)))

`l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4]
 print(list(set(l)))`

Comment: Поскольку множество, по определению, не поддерживает порядок элементов, то Ваше решение может вернуть как `[1, 2, 3, 4]` так и `[2, 4, 3, 1]`