# Как удалить из списка словари с повторяющимся полем?

Tags: python

У меня есть список словарей вроде такого:

```
[
    {'id': 1, 'name': 'one'},
    {'id': 2, 'name': 'two'},
    {'id': 1, 'name': 'one'},
    {'id': 3, 'name': 'three'}
]
```

Я хочу, чтобы остался список с уникальными `id` (неважно, что в остальных полях словаря). То есть, из примера выше должно получиться это:

```
[
    {'id': 1, 'name': 'one'},
    {'id': 2, 'name': 'two'},
    {'id': 3, 'name': 'three'}
]
```

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Удаление одинаковых элементов в отсортированном листе (списке)](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/575604/23044)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Чтобы оставить в списке только словари с уникальным id (убрать повторения):

```
result = list({d['id']: d for d in list_of_dicts}.values())
```

Это линейный по времени и по памяти алгоритм.

Результат:

```
[{'id': 1, 'name': 'one'},
 {'id': 2, 'name': 'two'},
 {'id': 3, 'name': 'three'}]
```

Answer (score 7):

```
from itertools import groupby


lst = [
    {'id': 1, 'name': 'one'},
    {'id': 2, 'name': 'two'},
    {'id': 1, 'name': 'one'},
    {'id': 3, 'name': 'three'}
]

key = lambda dct: dct['id']

lst.sort(key=key)

lst = [list(tpl[1])[0] for tpl in groupby(lst, key=key)]

print(lst)
```

Comment: можно упростить слегка: `[next(dups) for _, dups in groupby(lst, key=key)]` или просто: `list(more_itertools.unique_justseen(lst, key=key))` или вообще без сортировки: `result = list(more_utils.unique_everseen([{'id':1,...}, {'id":2, ...}], key=lambda d: d['id']))`

Comment: Действительно, так более ясно получилось. Плюс небольшая оптимизация, там где next вместо создания списка.

Answer (score 5):

Я бы, наверное, использовал словарь.

```
lst = [
    {'id': 1, 'name': 'one'},
    {'id': 2, 'name': 'two'},
    {'id': 1, 'name': 'one'},
    {'id': 3, 'name': 'three'}
]

d = {}

for a in lst: 
  d[a['id']] = a

d.items()
```

Comment: в конце: `lst = list(d.values())` не хватает.

Answer (score 4):

```
lst = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'one'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'two'}, {'id': 1, 'name': 'one'}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'three'}]

items = lambda d: tuple(d.items())
list(map(dict, set(map(items, lst))))
```

сравнение быстродействия способов:

```
from timeit import Timer
from itertools import groupby

def test_1(items=lambda d: tuple(d.items())):
    list(map(dict, set(map(items, lst))))

def test_2():
    d = {}
    for a in lst: d[a['id']] = a
    list(d.values())

def test_3(key=lambda dct: dct['id']):
    lst.sort(key=key)
    [next(dups) for _, dups in groupby(lst, key=key)]

def test_4():
    list({d['id']: d for d in lst}.values())

def test_5():
    result = []
    _id = []
    rapp = result.append
    iapp = _id.append
    for d in lst:
        i = d['id']
        if i not in _id:
            iapp(i)
            rapp(d)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    gbls = globals()
    for fn in sorted(k for k in gbls if k.startswith('test_')):
        print('{:<6} = {:.2} сек'.format(fn, Timer(gbls[fn]).timeit()))
```

out:

```
test_1 = 9.4 сек
test_2 = 1.8 сек
test_3 = 5.8 сек
test_4 = 1.9 сек
test_5 = 1.9 сек
```