# Как избежать повторения идущих подряд строк в файле

Tags: python, файлы

У нас есть файл input, в котором хранятся строки. Наша задача поместить в файл output только те строки, которые не повторяются с предыдущими. Учитель запретила использовать массивы, поэтому мы должны сравнивать строки только посредством filename.readLine().
Пример файла input:

```
apple
apple
apple
apple
banana
bargain
brick
brick
sample
sample
simple
text
text
text
```

Пример файла output:

```
apple
banana
bargain
brick
sample
simple
text
```

Вот мой код, который почему-то просто перепечатывает оригинальный файл:

```
fileFrom = open ('data.txt', 'r')
fileTo = open ('result.txt', 'w')

line = fileFrom.readline()

while line != '':
    if line == fileFrom.readline():
        line = fileFrom.readline()
    else:
        fileTo.write(line + '\n')
    line = fileFrom.readline()

fileFrom.close()
fileTo.close()
```

Если убрать `line = fileFrom.readline()` в цикле, то он вообще перепечатывает только первую строку. Очевидно, что условие if не выполняется, но я не могу понять, почему.

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Удаление одинаковых элементов в отсортированном листе (списке)](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/575604/23044)

Answer (score 1):

Если использовать массив нельзя, то предыдущую строку можно записать в переменную `prevline`:

```
fileFrom = open('data.txt', 'r')
fileTo = open('result.txt', 'w')

line = fileFrom.readline()
prevline = ""

while line != '':
    line = fileFrom.readline()
    if prevline != line:
        fileTo.write(line)
    prevline = line
```

Comment: спасибо, ваш подход сработал. только вот странно, что работает на всех компьютерах, кроме моего собственного.

Comment: @lili попробуйте запустить скрипт от имени администратора

Answer (score 1):

Так как повторяющиеся строки идут подряд в файле, то можно использовать [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), чтобы найти группы одинаковых смежных строк и записать только одну строку из каждой группы:

```
fileTo.writelines(uniq for uniq, _ in itertools.groupby(fileFrom))
```

Так как строки сравниваются буквально, то последняя строка должна иметь `'\n'`, чтобы как повторение считаться.

Можно руками это также реализовать:

```
prev = None
for line in fileFrom:
    if line != prev:
       prev = line
       fileTo.write(line)
```

Оба решения используют факт, что файл является итератором над строками в Питоне.

Answer (score 0):

вот такой код у меня в итоге получился. работает.всем спасибо большое!

```
fileFrom = open('data.txt', 'r')
fileTo = open('result.txt', 'w')
line = fileFrom.readline()
old_line = ''

while line != '':
    line = fileFrom.readline()
    if old_line != line: 
        fileTo.write(line)
    old_line = line
```