# Очистка списка от повторяющихся эелементов

Tags: python, python-3.x

Не работает очистка списка от повторяющихся элементов.
Не выводит ничего(

```
some_list = [12, 56, 91, 12, 15, 56, 12]
set(some_list)
```

Comment: `some_list = set(some_list)` - `set()` возвращает множество, а не меняет аргумент на лету...

Comment: [`print(list(filter(lambda x: x > 1, collections.Counter([12, 56, 91, 12, 15, 56, 12]))))`](https://repl.it/repls/PresentFrigidApplicationprogram) список будет без дубликатов и останется не отсортированным в отличии от `set()`

Comment: Простите) Я ничего не понял(

Comment: ну можно было для начала и самому погуглить https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459703/how-to-make-lists-contain-only-distinct-element-in-python

Comment: связанные вопросы [Удаление одинаковых элементов в отсортированном листе (списке)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/575604/23044), [Как найти все дублирующиеся элементы в списке и количество их повторов?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/533108/23044), [Вернуть массив, состоящий только из неуникальных элементов данного массива](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/621366/23044)

Comment: связанный вопрос 
[Удаление дубликатов строк из файла сохраняя порядок строк](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/631054/23044)

Comment: Похожие вопросы: [Removing duplicates in lists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7961363/4279), [How do you remove duplicates from a list whilst preserving order?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/480214/4279)

Answer (score 2):

Когда вам не нужно сохранить порядок, вы можете сделать так:

```
some_list = [12, 56, 91, 12, 15, 56, 12]
some_list = list(set(some_list))        # использовать set(), затем назад к списку - list()

print(some_list)
```

Вывод:

> ```
> [56, 91, 12, 15]
> ```

Но когда вы хотите сохранить порядок, можете сделать так:

```
new_list = []

for el in some_list:
    if el not in new_list:
        new_list.append(el)

print(new_list)
```

Вывод:

> ```
> [12, 56, 91, 15]
> ```

Comment: можно упомянуть, что вариант с set не сохраняет исходный порядок элементов и работает только для хэшируемых элементов.  Вариант с вложенным циклом является квадратичным по времени. Ввод не ограничен в вопросе, поэтому это гораздо хуже линейного варианта с set(). По ссылкам под вопросом можно найти решения, которые сохраняют порядок и/или не являются квадратичными.

Comment: вот в конце ответа подробнее [о разнице между линейными и квадратичными алгоритмами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/596463/23044)

Answer (score 1):

Множеством очищаем список от повторений, а затем превращаем в список для дальнейшей удобной работы с данными.

```
def without_repetition(input_list):
    return list(set(input_list))

print(without_repetition([12, 56, 91, 12, 15, 56, 12]))  #[56, 91, 12, 15]
```

Comment: В питоне не используется верблюжья нотация, поэтому: `withoutRepetition` -> `without_repetition`,  `inputList` -> `input_list`

Comment: Дурная привычка из-за работы с PyQt, где "верблюд" используется

Comment: Все же было гораздо проще в учебнике, но по-прежнему не работает
some_list = ['a', 'b', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'b', 'f', 's']
print = (some_list)
print = (set(some_list))

Comment: print( withoutRepetition(['a', 'b', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'b', 'f', 's']) )   #['f', 'g', 'b', 's', 'a', 'd']

Comment: К сожалению выдает ошибку

Comment: some_list = ['a', 'b', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'b', 'f', 's']
print( withoutrepetition (['a', 'b', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'b', 'f', 's']) )

Comment: some_list = ['a', 'b', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'b', 'f', 's'];
print( withoutRepetition(some_list) )

Comment: Сработало вот так:
some_list = ['a', 'b', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'b', 'f', 's']
print( set(['a', 'b', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'b', 'f', 's']) )

Comment: Я использовать 'list(set(input_list))' для того, чтобы функция возвращала тип list, который более гибкий в работе. Проверьте правильность написание имени функции, в частности регистр

Comment: Большое спасибо

Comment: @mydiamondsdancing, привычка привычкой, а исправляться никогда не поздно )

Comment: @gil9red не спорю, со временем перейду на такой стиль(точно не знаю, как он называется)

Comment: Для себя вы можете писать в любом стиле и вообще, если в текущем проекте используется свой стиль, руководство говорит, что не нужно весь код рефакторить, однако выкладывая публично код, нужно придерживаться общего стиля. Я вам уже 2 раза намекал на это :D Вас не будут карать за то, что не следуете общему стилю, но могут отнестись к такому коду хуже. Вы можете найти [русскоязычное](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/pep-8-rukovodstvo-po-napisaniyu-koda-na-python.html#id28) описание руководства или оригинальное: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names

Comment: @mydiamondsdancing, почему не принять совет [gil9red](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/201445/gil9red) и не изменить `withoutRepetition` на `without_repetition` и  `inputList` на `input_list` прямо в вашем ответе?

Comment: @MarianD уже исправился, извиняюсь за задержку

Comment: как зделать так щтобы можна было не вводить числа в ручную а щтобы они переносились со списка

Comment: @РусланВласенко Я конечно извиняюсь, но для начала выучить основы русского языка. Такая грамматика это уже слишком